# Implementing window like "Eclipse About Window"

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, window

I want to ask you about:

1. Which type is the "About" window displayed in Eclipse Juno 4.2 vía Help-->About Eclipse: is it `JFrame`, `JDialog` or another?
2. How can I get the About window via code in Java? Because until now I couldn't obtain via code a similar window (with Maximize, Minimize buttons). Also remembering that this About window doesn't appear in the Windows Button Bar (so perhaps it's a `JDialog`).

This is what the About window for Eclipse Indigo looks like (Juno is pretty much the same in look):

[image: Eclipse Indigo About Window]

Comment: Thanks for your support. Remembering that my IDE now is Juno, but it applies for my question.

Comment: FWIW: it should be a modal `JDialog` with the appropriate parent window provided in the constructor (not `null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Help>About` window in Eclipse is not a Swing dialog at all. Like other parts of the Eclipse rich-client platform, it is built atop SWT.

The class is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog`. It's a modal, resizable dialog, built atop a native window with dialog trim and a maximize/restore button.

In an RCP application, its text and image are specified in a *.product file. It's not intended to be instantiated directly outside the Eclipse codebase.

If you need to work in Swing, you could implement a similar window, using `JFrame`. If you have the option of building an SWT/RCP application, you could get this dialog for free, along with a huge, tasty menu of additional common high-level functionality.

Comment: So because my project is Swing-based... I can't integrate these class to my project purely?

Comment: Is it difficult to say if SWT is better than Swing or viceversa? I mean, now in Java RCP projects which kind of GUI library do we have to use?

Comment: Not easily. It's not designed for use in Swing applications, and not intended for external use. It is possible to use Swing components inside of an RCP application. It's probably easier to implement your own dialog. I'm adding a few details above.

Comment: Both Swing and SWT have their advantages in different circumstances. An RCP application is built atop the SWT widget toolkit and the higher-level JFace library, as well as a huge number of additional available plug-ins.